# Start {{@index}} on 1 and not 0 in Handlebars, no template

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

I am looping through items using @each, and I want to start with index 1 and not 0. I have tried something like

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper("inc", function(value, options)
{
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});
```

and then

```
{{inc @index}}
```

But when I am loading the page, it says

Error: Missing helper: "inc"

What is another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

in your app.js :

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({ defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs', helpers: {
  inc: function(value, options){
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
  }
} }));
```

Comment: Please add some information to your post why your code helps :)